# How to insert self referencing entities into sql?

Tags: c#, t-sql

Assume I have the following structure for a sql table:

Name:
`UserTable`

Fields:

- `ID` bigint IDENTITY(1, 1)
- `Name` nvarchar(200) NOT NULL
- `ParentID` bigint NULL

Note:

`ParentID` is a self referencing foreign key to the primary key `ID` which is optional.

Now switching over to my c#-project, I find myself wondering how to insert this entity many times from an import.

```
    public static void InsertTable(DataTable table)
    {
        var connection = CreateConnection();
        string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] (Name, ParentID) " +
            "OUTPUT INSERTED.ID " +
            "VALUES " +
            "(@Name, @ParentID)";

        using (connection)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = table.Rows[i];

                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    InsertParameters(row, command);
                    long insertedID = (long)command.ExecuteScalar();

                    row["ID"] = insertedID;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I set the parameters like this:

```
    private static void InsertParameters(DataRow row, SqlCommand command)
    {
        string name = (string)row["Name"];
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);

        if(row["ParentID"] is DBNull)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentID", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentID", (long)row["ParentID"]);
        }
    }
```

I figured that I won't be able to insert these entities into this table at any order. My approach was to try to insert entities with no reference to any parent first. While this can work in a simple example like this, I struggle to find an approach for multiple references.

I worked around this by just mapping the relations in some `Dictionary<T1, T2>` objects and revisit the ones with references later, when the `ID`-property of the referenced entity is set.

My problem with this is that I can clearly map one `DataRow` to another, but not insert them so easy, when I can not know the ID beforehand. I'd like to know if there are some better approaches to this.

I stumbled upon this particular problem while doing an import for some customer-related data. My solution so far is okay-ish, but not satisfactory. One case where it all breaks could be a loop reference, I think.

Anyway,

How would you tackle this problem and how to improve my method so far?

Answer (score 1):

I would create stored procedure which does the whole process and can get the ids as such. Then in C# code call the sproc.

---

This is an example from my nuget package [SQLJSONReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLJSONReader) ([github project page](https://github.com/CheetahChrome/SQLJSONReader)) where the SQL server sproc returns JSON and my reader `ExecuteJsonReader` then converts the table result, to a string of JSON.

```
string sproc = "dbo.DoIt";
string result;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sproc, conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 600 })
    {
        if (parameters != null)
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

        var reader = await cmd.ExecuteJsonReaderAsync();

        result = await reader.ReadAllAsync();
    }
}
```

So your process is similar, just use your own reader.

Comment: That approach seems doable. Do you have resources or examples on that?

Comment: Its the exact same process as what you have now, `SQLParameter`s and all but you have to update the command to use a sproc. Example provided.

Comment: I find the SQLJsonReader interesting. I will surely look into it. This leaves me clueless on how to insert self references in a stored procedure tho. I feel like you outsourced the problem. The problem was not the process that we both described (slightly differently), but to resolve the references while inserting in sql or c#, where ever it suits best. Thanks for the interesting input tho.

Comment: Np, it is an `alternate` solution. Most of my recent work has been to have rest web services send JSON Models out to the callers...and having SQL Server generate the JSON in SQL to then be returned as that JSON from the sproc, was the most efficient way. Than having the web service convert the old style table data to JSON models.